# Combine Consecutive Rows with the Same column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have something that looks like this.
How do I go from this:

```
    0             d
0   The         DT
1   Skoll       ORGANIZATION
2   Foundation  ORGANIZATION
3   ,           ,
4   based       VBN
5   in          IN
6   Silicon     LOCATION
7   Valley      LOCATION
```

to this:

```
    0                       d
0   The                     DT
1   Skoll Foundation        ORGANIZATION
3   ,                       ,
4   based                   VBN
5   in                      IN
6   Silicon Valley          LOCATION
```

Answer (score 13):

@rfan's answer of course works, as an alternative, here's an approach using pandas [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

The `.groupby()` groups the data by the 'b' column - the `sort=False` is necessary to keep the order intact.  The `.apply()` applies a function to each group of b data, in this case joining the string together separated by spaces.

```
In [67]: df.groupby('b', sort=False)['a'].apply(' '.join)
Out[67]: 

b
DT                       The
Org         Skoll Foundation
,                          ,
VBN                    based
IN                        in
Location      Silicon Valley
Name: a, dtype: object
```

EDIT:

To handle the more general case (repeated non-consecutive values) - an approach would be to first add a sentinel column that tracks which group of consecutive data each row applies to, like this:

```
df['key'] = (df['b'] != df['b'].shift(1)).astype(int).cumsum()
```

Then add the key to the groupby and it should work even with repeated values.  For example, with this dummy data with repeats:

```
df = DataFrame({'a': ['The', 'Skoll', 'Foundation', ',', 
                      'based', 'in', 'Silicon', 'Valley', 'A', 'Foundation'], 
                'b': ['DT', 'Org', 'Org', ',', 'VBN', 'IN', 
                      'Location', 'Location', 'Org', 'Org']})
```

Applying the groupby:

```
In [897]: df.groupby(['key', 'b'])['a'].apply(' '.join)
Out[897]: 
key  b       
1    DT                       The
2    Org         Skoll Foundation
3    ,                          ,
4    VBN                    based
5    IN                        in
6    Location      Silicon Valley
7    Org             A Foundation
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: You do not need the lambda there.

Comment: I considered this, but wouldn't this also concatenate non-consecutive but repeated values in the second column? If the second column is unique besides consecutive repeats then it would be fine.

Comment: Thanks ari.  @rfan - good point, this will join any repeated data so your answer handles that case correctly while this doesn't

Comment: @rfan you are right, if the data is repeated it would be a problem. But you should be able to use a second key column to further split up the groupby in many cases.

Comment: @ari Right. I think that, with the addition of creating another key column to track non-consecutive repeats, this method probably scales better than my solution to larger or more complex problems.

Comment: An example of how to produce such a column could be (assuming that the DT key could be used as a sentinel value) `df['helper'] = (np.where(df.d=='DT',df.index,np.nan))`
`df.helper.fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: @chrisb : if you include the secondary key to track non-consecutive repeats, I'll accept this as the answer. Because, currently, it groups all similar values, which is not what I require.

Comment: @ari sorry, I copy/pasted what you have, but it gives me a list of numbers. I'm not entirely sure how this is supposed to work. Could you or chrisb post an integrated solution that takes care of consecutive repeats only?

Answer (score 2):

I actually think the groupby solution by @chrisb is better, but you would need to create another groupby key variable to track non-consecutive repeated values if those are potentially present. This works as a quick-and-dirty for smaller problems though.

---

I think this is a situation where it's easier to work with basic iterators, rather than try to use pandas functions. I can imagine a situation using groupby, but it seems difficult to maintain the consecutive condition if the second variable repeats.

This can probably be cleaned up, but a sample:

```
df = DataFrame({'a': ['The', 'Skoll', 'Foundation', ',', 
                      'based', 'in', 'Silicon', 'Valley'], 
                'b': ['DT', 'Org', 'Org', ',', 'VBN', 'IN', 
                      'Location', 'Location']})

# Initialize result lists with the first row of df
result1 = [df['a'][0]]  
result2 = [df['b'][0]]

# Use zip() to iterate over the two columns of df simultaneously,
# making sure to skip the first row which is already added
for a, b in zip(df['a'][1:], df['b'][1:]):
    if b == result2[-1]:        # If b matches the last value in result2,
        result1[-1] += " " + a  # add a to the last value of result1
    else:  # Otherwise add a new row with the values
        result1.append(a)
        result2.append(b)

# Create a new dataframe using these result lists
df = DataFrame({'a': result1, 'b': result2})
```

Comment: could you explain your process a bit? it seems to be working for me

Comment: Something you could do to speed it up would be to boolean mask on those rows where you have duplicate values: `df[df.d.isin((df.d.value_counts() > 1).index[df.d.value_counts() > 1])]` this returns a dataframe containing just the duplicate rows